# color array to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have form where I put in a number there is saved in MySQL database. I would like a function where specific numbers get a specific background-color. That background-color is saved in the column `color` in my database. Furtheron the background-color should be return in my div tag.

**Example:**
if number is [1, 6, 59] make background blue
if number is [4, 12, 79] make background yellow

**Input form:**

```
<form id="myForm" action="select.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="numbervalue" id="numberinput">
    <input type="submit" id="sub" Value="Submit">
    <span id="result"></span>
</form>
```

**Insert PHP code:**

```
<?php
include('session.php');
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO numbertable(numbers, numdate, bgcolour) VALUES(?, NOW())");

// bind variable: 'd' for digit/tal, 's' for string
$stmt->bind_param('d',intval($_POST["numbervalue"]));   // bind

// execute prepared statement 
if ($stmt->execute()) { // tjek om udført:
    $success = true;
}

// luk statement
$stmt->close();

// luk connection
$mysqli->close();   

if($success) {
    echo "Insert Succesfull";
} else {
    echo "Failed: " .  $stmt->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your INSERT query will fail because the number of arguments do not match and there is a syntax error.

Comment: There is a lot of things in the code there will fail I think :) I am more looking for an overview perspective on the code, and if there is some things there are totally wrong, or I only have to adjust it. Best Regards.

Comment: What's your question or problem?

Comment: @MadsKristensen That is not really what this site is suited for. Stackoverflow is  a great place to come when you are having a specific problem that you need help with. I think your best bet would be to read some tutorials/examples about using PHP and MySQL, and refer to the PHP manual. When you hit a specific problem that stumps you, ask a question on SO.